# How implementation SQLite Join using spinner at Android Studio to get id from tables

Tags: java, android, sqlite, spinner

I've created 2 tables within an SQLite database, `stok` and `sales`

at DatabaseHelper.java

1. Create table `stok`

   ```
   String tbStok = "CREATE TABLE stok(id_stok INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, waktu_stok DATETIME, id_sales INTEGER, stok INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY id_sales REFERENCES sales(id_sales)";
   ```
2. Create table `sales`

   ```
   String tbSales = "CREATE TABLE sales(id_sales INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, nama VARCHAR, kodesales VARCHAR, username VARCHAR, password VARCHAR, level INTEGER)";
   ```
3. Create List Data from SQLite

   ```
   public List<String> getSpinnerSales(){
       List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();

       // Select All Query
       String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + "sales";

       SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
       Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

       // looping through all rows and adding to list
       if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
           do {
               labels.add(cursor.getString(0));
               labels.add(cursor.getString(1));
           } while (cursor.moveToNext());
       }

       // closing connection
       cursor.close();
       db.close();

       // returning lables
       return labels;
   }
   ```
4. Display on Spinner

   ```
   private void loadSpinnerSales() {
       // database handler
       DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());

       // Spinner Drop down elements
       List<String> lables = db.getSpinnerSales();

       // Creating adapter for spinner
       ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
               android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);

       // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
       dataAdapter
               .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

       // attaching data adapter to spinner
       spsales.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
   }
   ```
5. Test if spinner selected

   ```
       spsales.setOnItemSelectedListener(new 
           AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
           @Override
           public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {
               String label = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
               Log.d("label:", label);
           }

           @Override
           public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

           }
       });
   ```

[image: Wireframe of spinner, value needed = id_sales]

I need `id_sales` to put values and save to other tables SQLite, but the spinner must display the name of sales.

Answer (score 1):

the best way is to use custom adapter then
 you can pass List of objects (in your case is"list of sales id and name" )to the adapter not just a List of strings,
then on item selected you will get the selected object 
then you can get whatever you need id or name 
you can follow this link to make custom adapter 
https://abhiandroid.com/ui/custom-spinner-examples.html

Answer (score 0):

I **Solve** this problems with edited the code

```
// looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                labels.add(cursor.getString(0)+cursor.getString(1));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
```

And at spinner on item selected manipulate with substring

```
spsupir.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {
                String label = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                String ids = String.valueOf(label).substring(0,1);
                Log.d("label:", ids);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
```

Code edited

```
String label = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
String ids = String.valueOf(label).substring(0,1);
Log.d("label:", ids);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Another Solve Problems**

Step 1 Create the model class

```
public class Sales {
    String id_sales,nama;

    public Sales(String id_sales, String nama) {
        this.id_sales = id_sales;
        this.nama = nama;
    }

    public String getId_sales() {
        return id_sales;
    }

    public void setId_sales(String id_sales) {
        this.id_sales = id_sales;
    }

    public String getNama() {
        return nama;
    }

    public void setNama(String nama) {
        this.nama = nama;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return nama;
    }
}
```

Step 2 Put all data from SQLite table sales

```
//Data spinner supir
    public ArrayList<Sales> getSpinnerSales(){
        ArrayList<Sales> salesList = new ArrayList<>();

        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + "sales";

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                salesList.add(new Sales(cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1)));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // closing connection
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        // returning lables
        return salesList;
    }
```

Step 3 Generate void to consume data from sqlite aa Activity

```
private void loadSpinnerSales() {
        // database handler
        DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
        ArrayList<Sales> salesList = db.getSpinnerSales();
        ArrayAdapter<Sales> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Sales>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, salesList);
        spsales.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

Step 4 Load method at OnCreate

```
    spsales = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spSales);
    loadSpinnerSales();

    spsales.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Sales sales = (Sales) parent.getSelectedItem();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),sales.getId_sales(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
```